# Using System.Data Instead of System.Data.SqlClient

Tags: c#, namespaces, sqlclient

I have a question of how to use `System.Data` and `System.Data.SqlClient`.

In the following example I've used `System.Data.SqlClient` namesspace. Can I write `System.Data` instead of `System.Data.SqlClient` here, because SqlClient is **already included** in the `System.Data` namespace?

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // First access the connection string.
    // ... This may be autogenerated in Visual Studio.
    string connectionString =
                     ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;
    //
    // In a using statement, acquire the SqlConnection as a resource.
    //
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        //
        // Open the SqlConnection.
        //
        con.Open();
        //
        // The following code uses an SqlCommand based on the SqlConnection.
        //
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Dogs1", con))
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
          while (reader.Read())
          {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",
            reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2));
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then no. You have to be explicit with namespaces. If you wanted to access DataTable in your example you would need to include System.Data - but that wouldn't give you access to any of the nested namespaces.

From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423(VS.80).aspx)

> Create a using directive to use the types in a namespace without
>   having to specify the namespace. A using directive does not give you
>   access to any namespaces that are nested in the namespace you specify.